# Gmail Delay Send Failing- but I didn't try to send any emails

Tags: google-apps-script

I keep getting emails every night at around 8pm that Gmail Delay Send has failed and showing a summary of the failures. The error message says "Authorization is required to perform that action". Every night, there are 288 "failures".

Here's the thing, though- I haven't tried to use Gmail Delay send in roughly 6 months! Not sure what is going on, has my email been hacked?

Comment: You might want to post your question at the GMail help forum: [Link to GMail help forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/gmail)  It's easy to misunderstand what Stack Overflow is for.  Unfortunately, Google has guided people here thinking that Stack Overflow is a general support site.  But it's not.  Stack Overflow is for unique programming questions, or questions about the code editor.  You question is more about general usage.  If you think your account has been hacked, immediately change your password.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely coming from an app that you authorized before.
"Authorization is required to perform that action" probably means you revoked the access to that app through your account dashboard and it's been trying to run.

If this is an app you created then you can visit the link in the mail and remove the [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) there.